# How would I define an interface that expects most keys to share a type, and expects specific keys to differ?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type that expects almost every key's value to be the same type. However, I also want to require that certain keys' values must be of a different type.

```
interface Item<T, U> {
  [key: string]: T;
  specificKey?: U;
}
```

This predictably gives an error:

```
Property 'specificKey' of type 'U' is not assignable to string index type 'T'.
```

My first thought was to attempt to use Exclude:

```
interface Item<T, U> {
  [key: Exclude<string, 'specificKey'>]: T;
  specificKey?: U;
}
```

However, this also gives an error:

```
An index signature parameter type cannot be a type alias.
```

Is there a way to set `[key: string]` to apply to all strings except `specificKey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation in TS. See [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) for detail. Currently there's no way to properly specify exactly the type you need. The closest is to use an intersection type:

```js
type Item<T, U> = { [k: string]: T } & { specificKey: U }
```

But this workaround only works on the "read" side:

```js
let item: Item<boolean, number>

// to read, it's fine
const bool = item['foobar']  // good
const num = item.specificKey // good
```

It still breaks on "write" side:

```js
// to write, TS raises same incompatible error
let item: Item<boolean, number> = { specificKey: 1, foobar: true }
//  ~~~~~ <-- Property 'specificKey' is incompatible with index signature.
//            Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

// you have to mute it with `as any`
let item: Item<boolean, number> = { specificKey: 1, foobar: true } as any
```